# how to make radio buttons behave in a mutually exclusive way

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I was to trying to update my checkbox value based on checked..But the problem I'm facing is i can't uncheck the old checkbox checked ..So when i click on the new checkbox the old one should be uncheck...I have used laravel platform where table header comes from database and from database the old checkbox value came..

here is my blade view :

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>SL No</th>
          <th>Name</th>
            @foreach($roles as $row)         
          <th>{{$row->label}}</th>
            @endforeach
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <?php $i=1; ?>
             @foreach($users as $user)
               @foreach($user->roles as $row)
                 <tr>
                    <td>{{$i}}</td>
                    <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
                        @foreach($roles as $role)
                    <td>

                        @if($role->role == $row->role)
                          <input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox" checked=""  >
                        @else 
                          <input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox">
                        @endif

                    </td>   
                      @endforeach
                   </tr>
                      <?php $i++; ?>
                  @endforeach
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

Here is the javascript i used for check only one checkbox .

```
 $('.myCheckbox').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
});
```

anybody could help me to find out the solution please?

Comment: better to use radio buttons if need to check only one

Comment: Yeah, what @bluemoon said. Why not simply use a radio button? :/

Comment: so question over?

Comment: yes i also think radio buttons or a drop down is more suited for this

Comment: The problem is when i use radio button . ..all the radio button got selected if i select all of them, which shouldn't happen.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You should be asking how to make radio buttons behave in a mutually exclusive way (you give them the same `name` attribute) not asking how to make a checkbox behave like a radio button.

Comment: Problem is with your `value`, Change the `value="1"` to something else and change the type to radio button.

Comment: Even though i change the value >> i got same result 
http://imgur.com/3Y7KOeX

Comment: `@if($role->role == $row->role)` is getting true both the time. Try printing same.

Comment: @PankitGami if i print same, all checkbox value will be checked ..right??

Comment: @Mamun sorry ..i may be misleading you. your solution couldn't give you the appropriate solution..thanks!

Comment: @User57 If condition is true every time, Checkbox will be checked every time.

Answer (score 0):

Either use radio buttons, or iterate over all checkboxes setting the `checked` value to false and only checking the just clicked checkbox.

Here is an example.

```js
var container = document.querySelector('.container');

container.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
  [].slice.call(this.children).forEach(function(input) {
    input.checked = false;
  })
  evt.target.checked = true;
})
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="checkbox"> Foo
  <input type="checkbox"> Bar
  <input type="checkbox"> Baz
</div>
```